# jQuery how to build a link with json?, error

Tags: jquery, load

i have this:

```
    $.get('xxx.php', { username: userName },
    function(data){
        var get_back = data;
        alert(get_back);
});
```

this will return `get_back=12345`

and i'm trying to build this:

```
url: "http://www.test.com/users/" + get_back,
```

the result to be `http://www.test.com/users/12345`

for some reason it doesn't want to work. If i hard-code the `12345` in the link it will work. i've also tryed `url: "http://www.test.com/users/" + get_back + "",` and `url: 'http://www.test.com/users/' + get_back,`

any ideas?

edit:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify(formData),
dataType: "json",
url: "http://www.test.com/users/" + get_back + "",
success: function(t){    alert(t);  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the complete javascript for what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: post edited, see changes

Comment: i updated my post below with the ajax call you added

Answer (score 0):

that because `get_back` might be in the scope of everything else. either you can call `get_back` before the `$.get` call and it will be global or you can put it all into on object like this:

```
var get = {
   get_back: null,
   init: function(username){
      var self = this;
      $.get('xxx.php', { username: userName },
          function(data){
              self.get_back = data;
              self.runAjax(); //run the ajax when get_back is instantiated
          }
      });

   },
   runAjax: function(){
      var self = this;
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data: JSON.stringify(formData),
         dataType: "json",
         url: "http://www.test.com/users/" + self.get_back + "",
         success: function(t){    alert(t);  }
         });
   }
}

//to use it:
get.init(username);
//to use get_back
alert(get.get_back);
```

**UPDATED WITH AJAX**

you might have to add `formdata` to the object somehow, i dont know where that was created